# Iterate on all check rows in JQuery datatable

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a Jquery datatable with a checkbox. I want to iterate on all checked rows and display it on an alert. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#ItemDT").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Home/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Name","width": "300px" }, 
                { "data": "Brand" },
                { "data": "ReplenishLimit" },
                { "data": "ReplenishQuantity" },
                { "data": "Quantity" }, 


            ],
            'columnDefs': [{
                'targets': 5,
                'searchable': false,
                'orderable': false,
                "data": "Id",
                'className': 'dt-body-center',
                'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'
                        + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
                }
            }],
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is a "checked row"? Or do you mean you just want to iterate over the results? Have you read https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows() ?

Comment: There is a check box on that datatable, I want to get the values on checked checkboxes

Comment: Then I suggest reading the documentation I linked to. Have you tried? :)

Comment: can u make fiddle with sample data @AdolfBernardMoncawe?

Comment: i can't, my data is on a server

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following way to get the checked rows from `table`. sample data from `datatable` blog is used here.

HTML

```
<table id="ItemDT">
 <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Get Checked" id="btnGetchecked" />
```

JS

```
$(function() {

    dataTable = $("#ItemDT").DataTable();

    $('body').on('click', '#btnGetchecked', '', function() {
        var CheckedRow = $("#ItemDT tbody tr").filter(function() {

            if ($(this).find('td:eq(0) > input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                return $(this).html();
            }
        });

        $.each(CheckedRow, function(key, value) {
            console.log(key);
            console.log(value);
        });



    });


});
```

here `value` holds the each checked rows. hope this helps.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cn8rexua/)

Comment: This looks great. But I think this approach fails when your table has multiple pages. Any luck with multi page iteration